# Image drop does not occur first time but happens second time using Jquery

Tags: jquery

This is my first question on the site.Most of the time I got the answer searching on this forum but this time could not find the solution so posting it here.

I have a page with one droppable div and one input text on it. For drop, i am using plugin jquery.filedrop.

The very first row is created on bean loading through jsf datatable.When i enter description, the description is saved in db(using ajax) and a new row containing drop div and input text is created. now user can drop the image on div. But when i drop the image first time it ignores and image does not appear but second time it recognizes and drops the image appropriately and saves in db. I am not able to resolve this issue and need help. Please find the JQuery code snippet below. Thanks a lot for your time and effort in advance.

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var processingId =$('#processingId').val();
var tattooPath = $('#path').val();  
var userName = $('#userName').val();    
var count=1;
$(document).on('change', '.descriptionInputBox', function(e){
    var descriptionInputBox = $(this);
    var input = $(this).find('.inputTextTattoo');

    var dropBOX = $('.dropbox');
    var pid = descriptionInputBox.attr('pid');
    var imageLocation = descriptionInputBox.attr('imageLocation');
    var imageName = 'image'+count+'.jpg';

    if(e.type == 'change'){

        if(descriptionInputBox.attr('imageName')== ""){
            var description= input.val();
            alert(description);
            descriptionInputBox.attr('imageName',imageName);
            var parentTR = descriptionInputBox.parent().parent();
            var td = parentTR.children('td').eq(0);
            td.children('div').eq(0).attr('imageName',imageName);

            var html = $('<tr><td><div class="dropbox" pid="" description="" imageLocation="" user="" processingId="" imageName=""><img class="tattooImage" src="" width="100px" height="100px"  ><div class="progressHolder"><div class="progressTattoo"></div></div></div></td><td><div class="descriptionInputBox" pid="" descriptionValue=""    imageLocation="" user="" processingId="" imageName=""><input type="text" class="inputTextTattoo" value="" name="descrip"/></div></td></tr>');

            $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().append(html);
            count=count+1;
            html.find('.dropbox').attr('imageName','image'+count+'.jpg');
            html.find('.dropbox').attr('description',"");
            html.find('.descriptionInputBox').attr('imageName','image'+count+'.jpg');
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/TrooperExamIntranet/ProxyServlet/photos/'+ processingId +'/saveTattooDescription',
            data:{ cid: processingId,id: pid, imageLocation: imageLocation, description: input.val(), userName: userName,imageName: descriptionInputBox.attr('imageName'),tattooImagePath: tattooPath},

            success: function(data) {

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });

    }

    dropBOX.on(
                'dragover',
                function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
        );
    dropBOX.on(
                'dragenter',
                function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
        );
    dropBOX.on(
                'dragLeave',
                function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
        );
    dropBOX.on('drop', function(e){
            alert("test");
            var dropbox = $(this);
            var progressTattoo= $('.progressTattoo',dropbox);
            var progressHolder= $('.progressHolder',dropbox);
            /*  progressTattoo.addClass('progressTattoo');
                progressHolder.addClass('progressHolder');*/
            var image = $('img', dropbox);
            //image.addClass('tattooImage');
            var pid = dropbox.attr('pid');
            var imageNameDrop = dropbox.attr('imageName');
            var description= function() {
                var parentTR = dropbox.parent().parent();
                var description = parentTR.children('td').eq(1);
                var desc = description.find('.inputTextTattoo').val();                  
                return desc;
            };
            //var description = dropbox.attr('description');

            dropbox.filedrop({
                url: '../../ProxyServlet/photos/' + processingId + '/saveTattoo',
                dropZone: $(this),
                paramname:'formTattooUpload',
                maxfiles: 1,
                maxfilesize: 8, // in mb
                data: {
                    cid:processingId,
                    tattooImagePath:tattooPath,
                    id:pid,
                    description:description,
                    imageName:imageNameDrop,
                    userName:userName,
                },  

                beforeEach: function(file){
                    if(!file.type.match(/^image\//)){
                        alert('Only images are allowed!'); 
                        return false;
                    }

                },
                uploadStarted:function(i, file, len){

                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    image.hide();
                    progressHolder.width("100%");
                    progressHolder.show();
                    progressTattoo.width("0%");
                    progressTattoo.show();
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
                    $.data(file,progressTattoo);
                    $.data(file,image);

                    reader.onload = function(e){
                        image.attr('src',e.target.result);   
                        image.hide();

                    };

                },
                globalProgressUpdated: function(progress) {
                    progressTattoo.width(progress+ "%");
                    progressTattoo.show();
                },
                uploadFinished:function(i,file,response){
                    //image.addClass('done');
                    //progressHolder.width("100%");
                    progressTattoo.width("100%");


                },afterAll: function() {
                    progressTattoo.width("0%");
                    //progressHolder.hide();
                    image.show();

                },
                error: function(err, file, fileIndex, xhrstatus){
                    image.attr('src',"");
                    image.hide();
                    console.log(err);
                    switch(err) {
                    case 'BrowserNotSupported':
                        alert('Your browser does not support HTML5 file uploads!');
                        break;
                    case 'TooManyFiles':
                        alert('Too many files! Please select 1 at most!');
                        break;
                    case 'FileTooLarge':
                        alert(file.name+' is too large! Image uploads are limited to ' + maxfileSize +' MB or less.');
                        break;
                    case 'Not Found':
                        alert('The requested resource is not available to upload file ' + file.name);
                        break;
                    case 'Internal Server Error':
                        alert('File ' +  file.name +' is not uploaded properly. Please try again.');
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert('Error ' + err + ' occurred in uploading file ' + file.name +' Please try again later!');
                    break;
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your `dropbox.filedrop` part is only being called once the file is already dropped to the element. Furthermore, this is re-binding the dropping each time you actually drop the file there, possibly introducing multiple file uploads on subsequent drops.

You need to move this whole section outside your drop event binding code, i.e. move this whole section:

```
dropbox.filedrop({
  url: '../../ProxyServlet/photos/' + processingId + '/saveTattoo',
  dropZone: $(this),
  paramname:'formTattooUpload',
........
```

... outside of: `dropBOX.on('drop', function(e) { ...`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Its working!!!! I could not have figured it out.Thanks again....

Comment: no problem - would you care voting this answer up and accepting it if you found is useful please?

Comment: Thanks! I don't have enough reputation to vote up this answer now.Its denying my voting. I accepted the answer.I will vote up as soon as I can do it.